# ImportError no module named accounts

Tags: python, django

Trying to create simple login functionality using Django, and I'm pretty new to using python and django.  I've been searching for a while, but haven't found anything that fixes the problem.  I'm running Django using MS VS2010, so I'm working under Windows instead of the typical linux environment.  When run, I get this:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:1214/accounts/signup
Django Version: 1.4.3
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
No module named accounts
Exception Location: C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py in import_module, line 35
Python Executable:  C:\Python27\python.exe
Python Version: 2.7.3
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\brandon\\Desktop\\AdvancedLogin\\AdvancedLogin',
 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python27.zip',
 'C:\\Python27\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk',
 'C:\\Python27',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages']
```

I've got the 
`__init__.py` 
file in bot the main project directory, and the app directory, though I haven't modified them at all.
I'm not really sure where to go from here.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: So what is `accounts` supposed to be? Do you have such an app in your project? How are you referencing it?

Comment: Yes, accounts is an app inside the main project.  This project is a tutorial from here: http://peyman-django.blogspot.com/2010/03/full-easy-authentication-using.html
Should i edit my op to show the views and urls files from the accounts app?

Comment: You should be very careful using tutorials that are 3 years old. The first line of the tutorial reads "If you use the django framework 1.1 and want to setup an authentication feature quickly, here is what you need", and you are using Django 1.4.3. I haven't read the entire tutorial, but there are most likely better, more recent, options out there.

Comment: You must add "account" app in your installed_app in settings.py

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you add the accounts to your settings.py?

Comment: Yes, I just did added it under INSTALLED_APPS.  Ran syncdb after adding it, then ran the page.  Got the same error when I navigated to /accounts/signup. :(

Comment: I actually expected to see something added to the database (I'm just using sqlite3) after running syncdb after adding accounts to my settings.py.  However, it said no objects were installed.

Comment: have you tried playing around with the path of your installed app? For example it might be AdvancedLogin.accounts or something like that. What is the directory structure of your django project?

Comment: Well, manage.py lives under AdvancedLogin/AdvancedLogin.  The accounts app lives under AdvancedLogin/AdvancedLogin/accounts.
I'll try playing with the structure some and see if it will do anything, then post back results

Comment: Fixed! A simple error on my part dealing with the directory structure.  In Visual Studios, the structure looked correct, but the project didn't know that the app was in the place I told it it was.

Comment: Great to hear! It also scares me you are using Visual Studio for Django development :D

Answer (score 2):

For other people be sure to use the correct AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS. I've set up one for test but forgot it and i've got the same error.

Before i was :
**settings.py**

```py
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'accounts.backends.MyAuthBackend',
)
```

After : **settings.py**

```py
#Default one
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]
This same error I was getting when I included 'accounts' in my setting.py file in "INSTALLED_APPS". But I was using sublime editor so I forgot to save that file and got this error.
Simply you have to add this "accounts" this to INSTALLED_APPS. this worked for me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

the error concern the importation of the personnal backend authentication
before

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
   "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
   "account.authentication.EmailAuthBackend",
]
```

after

````
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
   "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
   "apps.account.authentication.EmailAuthBackend",
]```
````

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem, and the solution is the order of inserting the authentication.py files it should be directly to the account apps not the folder(if you have name name clash between the apps and folder authentication)
like this:
----account(apps)
---account
authentication.py
---EmailAuthBackend